# Global and Local Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, global

I'm trying to send a text message over Tkinter. So you input `sms:hello`. That sends a text message that says `hello`. To do this it emails the word using the AT&T email server and GMail. So the program reads `INFO.txt` which contains all the email authentications `g_user` `g_pass` and `m_num`. Then it uses those to send an email which sends the text message.

Now my problem is that `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g_user' referenced before assignment`. Which I know is caused by something not being a `global` variable. Can anyone help me out? I'm stumped...

```
root = Tk()
#open file
file=open('INFO.txt')
line=file.readline()
if 'Mobile_number:::' in line:
    m_num=line[16:]
if 'GMail_name:::' in line:
    g_user=line[13:]
if 'GMail_pass:::' in line:
    g_pass=line[13:]



def callback(event):
    text = inputfield.get()
    if 'sms:' in text:
        textmessage()



def textmessage():#sms:
    import smtplib
        #open file
    file=open('INFO.txt')
    line=file.readline()
    if 'Mobile_number:::' in line:
        m_num=line[16:]
    if 'GMail_name:::' in line:
        g_user=line[13:]
    if 'GMail_pass:::' in line:
        g_pass=line[13:]

        SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587

    sender = '{}@gmail.com'.format(g_user)
    password='{}'.format(g_pass)
    recipient = '{}@txt.att.net'.format(m_num)
    subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
    body = text[4:]

    "Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."

    body = "" + body + ""

    headers = ["From: " + sender,
               "Subject: " + subject,
               "To: " + recipient,
               "MIME-Version: 1.0",
               "Content-Type: text/html"]
    headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    session.login(sender, password)

    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
    session.quit()

    text2=text[4:]
    confirmation="SMS containing '{}' sent".format(text2)
    tex.insert(END,confirmation)



tex=Text(root)
tex.pack(side='right')


inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack(side='bottom')
inputfield.bind('<Return>', callback)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely with this line:

```
sender = '{}@gmail.com'.format(g_user)
```

because the `if` statement condition (`if 'GMail_name:::' in line`) is evaluating to `False` and then your `g_user` variable is never defined in the local scope of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g_user' referenced before assignment
```

A pretty good rule of thumb is to assume that the error message is telling the truth. In this case it is telling you two very important details:

- It thinks `g_user` is a local variable
- It thinks `g_user` was used before it was set

To solve this, you need to answer *why* to one or both of those questions. *Why* does it think it is local, and/or *why* does it think it wasn't set? If you mentally step through the code, you'll probably answer one or both of those questions.

For example, ask youself the question "how does g_user" get set if `'GMail_name:::' in line` returns false? Have you verified that the if statement is true? Is your code prepared to handle the case where it's false? Have you literally proven to yourself that the if statement is true, or are you just assuming it's true?

Also, answer this question: are you reading every line from INFO.txt, or are you reading a single line? If you're only reading a single line, is that intentional? It looks like you are expecting both the username and password to be at position `[13:]` in the line, which will be impossible if both values are different and both values are on the same line.

Since you are just now learning to program, don't just throw lines of code into a file and hope they work, and don't get others to solve your problems. *think* about what the computer is doing. Step through the code logically and the problems will become self-evident.